# Getting a declared constant array with nested Json values in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, constants

I am not sure if this is possible but here is the question:
I have the declared a constant grabbing partially an API's response body. 
For simplicity, I will declare the partial API response as follows:

```
const partialResponse = {
   "Name": "Marshall",
   "Color": "Blue",
}
```

I am declaring a constant based on a array which includes the API's response body (stringified).

```
const data = {
    "id": "123",
    "jsonValues": partialResponse
}
```

However, in my script, the following returns null when I am expecting "**Marshall**" as an output:

```
console.log(data.jsonValues.Name)
```

Comment: You should use JSON.parse method.

Comment: I just tested that in my browser's console and it is working just fine. It is possible you have more code that is messing you up?

Comment: Your snippet works. Maybe you could check the order of each event.

Comment: It's working. I've checked on Chrome browser.